# Convert Japan's date format (2013年11月24日) to normal date format (2013-11-24)

Tags: java, locale, date-format

I have a date picker field on my JSP page. While selecting that field, the date is displayed in Japanese format (`2013年11月24日`) in my text field. Now, while reading that date field in my controller, I am getting this value `2013年11月24日`.

How can I convert this date format into normal date format?

Comment: No such thing as "normal date format". Every culture has their own styles for formatting date-time values. And a few computer protocols define specific formats, the modern one being [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the format you've given is the default date format of the Japanese locale, so you can use the build in facility:

```
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, new Locale("ja"));
```

Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

IDEONE example: http://ideone.com/0W7szq

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, new Locale("ja"));
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
System.out.println(df.parse("2013年11月24日"));
```

Output:

> 2013年11月24日
>
> Sun Nov 24 00:00:00 GMT 2013

Edit:

Please note that this DateFormat class is not thread-safe, so you cannot make the instant static. If you do not want to create the instance again and again like above, you may want to look into the thread-safe variant in Joda time: [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Comment: Hi sir,Here the problem is while getting that value into controller we are getting different value.how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I.e. what type of data are you passing to the controller? How is that done? What do you expect to get and what do you actually get?

Comment: when ever i select the date using date picker the date is in japan format(2013年11月24日) i am getting that date in the controller but the date is coming in different format like(2013^&11%&24*^) but those symbols are not exactly i am giving as example...Thanks for the reply...

Comment: I think that's character encoding problem. You'll have to check the encoding of the page, the form (containing the date picker) and the encoding your controller is expecting. You can use the network tab your browser's developer's tool (or similar) to see what data is actually being posted.

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by billc.cn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20174443/642706) is correct but outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## java.time

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.forLanguageTag("ja") ) ;
String input = "2013年11月24日" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

> input: 2013年11月24日
>
> ld.toString(): 2013-11-24

[See live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/bTOcPG).

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You should be **using `LocalDate` objects to hold your date-only values in your business logic** and data model. Generate the strings only as needed for presentation such as display in your JSP page.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are the delimiters always the same?
If so, can't you just use `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy年MM月dd")`?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I will try this now and I will get back to you